# Query consecutive words using match_phrase elasticsearch works unexpected

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

I have the parameter `name` as a [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/text.html):

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Because of the nature of `text` type in ElasticSearch, matchs every word on the phrase. That's why in some cases I get the next results:

```
POST /example-tags/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
     "name": "Jordan Rudess was born in 1956"
    }
  }
}

// Results 
{
  "took" : 28,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.1596613,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "example-tags",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6101e538bc8ec610aff699e4",
        "_score" : 4.1596613,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Jordan Rudess"
        }
      },
       {
        "_index" : "example-tags",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "610123538bc8ec61034ff699e4",
        "_score" : 4.1796613,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Alice in Chains"
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, in the text `Jordan Rudess was born in 1956` I get the result `Alice in Chains` just for the word `in`. I want to avoid this behaviour.
If I try:

```
POST /example-tags/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
     "name": "Dream Theater keyboardist's Jordan Rudess was born in 1956"
    }
  }
}
// Results
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

So, in the past example I was expecting to get the `Jordan Rudess` tag name but I get empty results.
I need to get the maximum ocurrences in `tag.name` of consecutive words in a phrase. How can I achieve that?

Comment: With match_phrase you are checking for the whole phrase. If you are only looking for the doc with name `Jordan Rudess`, shouldn't your query do : 'match_phrase' : { 'name' :  'Jordan Rudess' }

Comment: I'm looking for the consecutive words `Jordan Rudess` in any form, not just matching the exact tag name.

Comment: But look at what you are searchin for. Then search for Jordan Rudess, not the whole sentence right?

Comment: `match_phrase` is use to do proximity matching, by default it will include a `slop` of 0, and all terms will be required, match will use operator `OR` by default so you can change to `AND` if you do not care about proximity, you can also use `span_near` if you want to be able to specify that you want ordered terms